# How to add and use a razor editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have tried to find documentation or samples on how to incorporate razor editor templates into a project.  the following answer on another thread may fix a problem I am having but I do not know how to incorporate it into my project.  It is no doubt easy.

here is the solution I do not know how to incorporate:
[Client-side validation of input type date does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516940/client-side-validation-of-input-type-date-does-not-work)

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://dineshkumara.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc-3-razor-editor-template.html) is short info about adding `EditorTemplate`. In short words - you have to create directory *EditorTemplates* in *Views/Shared* and you should create a view with the same name as the model you want to create the editor for.

Remember that `EditorTemplate` for a model is used when calling `Html.EditorFor` with object of this model as argument. You should use them to provide editing possibilities, of course - if you want to create something that should only display data, use the same way to create `DisplayTemplate` (create *DisplayTemplates* directory). `DisplayTemplate` is rendered on `Html.DisplayFor` call with object of this model as argument.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will check the link out that you sent.

Answer (score 9):

There's some useful background on the default templates used by Html.Editor(For) and Html.Display(For) and how to override them using views in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates and View/Shared/DisplayTemplates directory of your project [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html).

I have a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/danmalcolm/mvc-razor-display-and-editor-templates) that contains Razor replacements for all of the default display and editor templates. Have a look at the demo web application - it should help you to see how things fit together. Then, copy the templates into your project and modify the parts you need.