# Insert value on different models in one view MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model course, component, subcomponent and evaluation:

```
public class Course
    {
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
       (...)
        public virtual List<Component> Components { get; set; }
        public virtual List<UserCourse> Users { get; set; }
    }

 public class Component
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponents { get; set; }

    }

public class Subcomponent
    {
        public virtual int SubcomponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string TypeSub { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameSub { get; set; }
        (...)

        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subcomponent Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Childs { get; set; }

        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

    }

public class Evaluation
    {
        public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

        public virtual int UserCourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserCourse User { get; set; }

        public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to give a grade to each subcomponent (or component if the component doesn't have subcomponents) to each user. 
First i have a view that shows the users and the grades already given, like an index:

```
@model SGP.Models.Course

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Users
        </th>

        <th>
            Grades
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var x in Model.Users)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => x.User.UserName)
            </td>
            @foreach (var y in x.Evaluation)
            {
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => y.Component.NameComp)</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => y.Grade)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            }
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Give grade", "Comps", "Evaluation", new { id = x.UserCourseId }, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Then when press "Give grade", i have a search box to select the component wich the grade will be given.
The search will give a list of subcomponents of that component. Each component can have one or more subcomponents so the final grade to the component is the average of the subcomponents grades.
The view of the subcomponents:

```
@model SGP.Models.Component

<table>
    <tr>        
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NameComp)
        </th>       
        <th>
            Grade
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Subcomponents) {
    <tr>       
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameSub)
        </td>      

        <td>
           ???????
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

But in this view i need to get the UserCourseId previously selected and give a grade to the user in the selected subcomponent. How can i do that?
Thanks

EDIT:
Give grade:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListaSubs", "Evaluation", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.TextBox("text")
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="ButtonSearch" value="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

And controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("ListaSubs")]
    public ActionResult ListaSubs(string text)
      {
        var util = (db.Subcomponents.Where(m =>
        m.ComponentId.Equals(text)));
        return View("view", util);
       }
```

Comment: what does the "give grade" view look like and how is it displayed?

Comment: @Steve Its in the question now

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case, is to define a wrapper class and use it for view's model. Something like this:

```
public class MyWrapperClass
{
   public Course _Course { get; set; }
   public Component _Component { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Then in your view, you define your model as:

```
@model MyWrapperClass
```

For some controls you can simply use the following format for the properties:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model._Course.CourseId)
```

But in some cases, you probably have to create EditorTemplate or DisplayTemplate for each subclass and use the templates in the view.

To use Editor template, you need to use a UIHint attribute in the class definition.

Here is some links on how to use editor template in razor:

[How to add and use a razor editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770126/how-to-add-and-use-a-razor-editor-template)

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp-net-mvc/